# D3 - Separate tooltip values for 2 line charts - using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, d3.js, svg

In a simple example I have made 2 line charts and they both have bullets also. Now on hovering bullets they are showing values of tooltips which refer to y-axis frequency values. Now, my problem is how to know which node (blue or red) have I hovered, so I get its corresponding y-axis value (frequency or frequency2) on its tooltip. Pls help, as I cannot identify same in the following function:

**FUNCTION for tooltip:**

```
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
 });
```

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>

<head>

    <style>
        /* d3 tip */ 
        .d3-tip {
          line-height: 1;  font-weight: bold;  padding: 12px;  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  color: #fff;  border-radius: 2px;}
        /* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
        .d3-tip:after {box-sizing: border-box;  display: inline;  font-size: 10px;  width: 100%;  line-height: 1;  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);  content: "\25BC";  position: absolute;  text-align: center;}
        /* Style northward tooltips differently */
        .d3-tip.n:after {margin: -1px 0 0 0;  top: 100%;  left: 0;}
    </style> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.12/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.js"></script>



</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

    <svg></svg>

    <script>

        //module declaration 
        var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        //Controller declaration
        app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){

            $scope.svgWidth = 800;//svg Width
            $scope.svgHeight = 500;//svg Height 

            //Data in proper format 
            var data = [
                  {"letter": "A","frequency": "5.01", "frequency2":"8.08"},
                  {"letter": "B","frequency": "7.80", "frequency2": "12.13"},
                  {"letter": "C","frequency": "15.35", "frequency2":"6.12"},
            ];

                //removing prior svg elements ie clean up svg 
                d3.select('svg').selectAll("*").remove();

                //resetting svg height and width in current svg 
                d3.select("svg").attr("width", $scope.svgWidth).attr("height", $scope.svgHeight);

                //Setting up of our svg with proper calculations 
                var svg = d3.select("svg");
                var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
                var width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
                var height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                var tip = d3.tip()
                  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                  .offset([-10, 0])
                  .html(function(d) {
                    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
                  });

                svg.call(tip);

                //Plotting our base area in svg in which chart will be shown 
                var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                //X and Y scaling 
                var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.4);
                var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

                x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.frequency; })]);

                //Final Plotting 

                //for x axis 
                g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

                //for y axis 
                g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                    .append("text").attr("transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("text-anchor", "end");

                //the line function for path 
                var lineFunction = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) {return x(d.letter); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
                    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

                //defining the lines
                var path = g.append("path");

                //plotting lines
                path
                    .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
                    .attr("stroke", "blue")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("fill", "none");

                g.selectAll('.circles1')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append('circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) {
                    return x(d.letter);
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) {
                    return y(d.frequency);
                    })
                    .attr('r', 6)
                    .style("fill", "blue")
                    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

            // ------------------ 2nd Iteration -----------------------// 

                //the line function for path 
                var lineFunction = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d) {return x(d.letter); })
                    .y(function(d) { return y(d.frequency2); })
                    .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

                //defining the lines
                var path = g.append("path");

                //plotting lines
                path
                    .attr("d", lineFunction(data))
                    .attr("stroke", "red")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .attr("fill", "none");

                g.selectAll('.circles1')
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append('circle')
                    .attr('cx', function(d) {
                    return x(d.letter);
                    })
                    .attr('cy', function(d) {
                    return y(d.frequency2);
                    })
                    .attr('r', 6)
                    .style("fill", "red")
                    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
                    .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

        });

    </script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

[image]

> As you can see I only see same frequency value on both. I can change the code in following line:

```
   return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
```

to frequency2, but then both will have frequency values of red chart. How, to detect which node (blue or red) I hovered?

Also, you can see that only xlabel & 2 y-axis frequency values are sent to function, but no infor regarding which to has been hovered!

[image]

Comment: Noone to help? ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three solutions:

1) Create two tooltips. One would display `frequency` data and you would add its `show`/`hide` functions to the data which is mapped to the `frequency` data. The other would display `frequency2` data and you would add its `show`/`hide` functions to the data which is mapped to the `frequency2` data.

2) You can wrap the `tip.show` functions and pass it only the data which you want to be displayed:

```
// blue line
g.selectAll('...')
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tip.show({frequency: d.frequency})
  })

// red line
g.selectAll('...')
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    tip.show({frequency: d.frequency2})
  })
```

3) Split your data before binding it to your charts. Then, only the data for the circle which you are hovering will be passed to the tooltip.

```
var blueData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    letter: d.letter
    frequency: d.frequency
  };
})

var redData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    letter: d.letter
    frequency: d.frequency2
  };
})
```